# Golang http.Post leaves open socket

Tags: go

I have the following golang code which when invoked inside of it's own webserver, appears to not close the socket. This leads to a "too many open files" message.  I have read all about the Body.Close() stuff and as you can see it's in there, yet it still acts poorly.

What else am I missing about connection handling?

```
func sendRequest(ctx context.Context, endpoint, uri string, data []byte) (int, []byte) {
    reqID := requestIDFromContext(ctx)
    // The servers have internally signed certs which are technically "not trusted"
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    insecureclient := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

    // Build the correct URL
    url := endpoint + uri

    requestbody := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    // Send our request and check for errors.
    fmt.Println(reqID, "Forwarding request to URL:", url)
    resp, err := insecureclient.Post(url, "application/json", requestbody)
    if err != nil {
        // This is where things happen when the connect goes bad
        fmt.Println(reqID, err)
        return 500, []byte("{}")
        //return handleConnectionError(ctx, data, uri)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Read response
    responsebody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(reqID, err)
        responsebody = []byte("{}")
    }

    return resp.StatusCode, responsebody
}
```

FWIW, altering the code to use a 'http.NewRequest' and then an 'insecureclient.Do' along with a 'Request.Close = true' seems to fix the problem.

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible example it'd be easier for people to comment. Have you had a look at this issue, could it be related to idle connections not being closed in time? https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20166

Comment: Reading the full body & closing it is important to allow HTTP keepalive connection reuse. Does the server support keepalive? Are the requests to the same endpoint? Have you tried tweaking the settings of your `Client` and `Transport`, e.g. the timeouts, max idles, disabling keepalive, etc?

Comment: Almost everything is http/1.1 or http/2 now, so there should be no expectation for the socket to be closed after a single request, unless you specifically close it.

Comment: All the requests go to the same endpoint. I would expect them to get pipelined but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @MichaelBeattie: you're creating a new Transport for every request. You can't reuse the connections if you don't reuse the transport that contains them.

Comment: Each request that comes in triggers 1, maybe 2 outbound requests. How would you reuse the transport? Maybe as a global variable?

Comment: Yes, pass a variable around, or use a package level variable, just like any other data you need to share. You should also set the appropriate options on the transport. See the DefaultTransport for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each client (more precisely, transport) maintains its own connection pool. This means there is one connection "hanging" in keep-alive after each sendRequest call. Instead of creating a new client every time, re-use it.